# Eloquent code repetition in join query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a design pattern meant for laravel/eloquent to deal with the following code repetition:

A user has albums, an album has photos, a photo has tags.

I have a special query to join photos from a single album and tags.

```
public function GetJoinedAlbum()
{
    return Photos::where(...in a specific album ...)->
       join(... tags ...)-> ...
}
```

I use the same join query to join all the photos of a user with tags.

```
Photos::where(... belong to a specific user ...)
        join(... tags ...)->...
```

I can't use 'with' since I would like to continue querying the result

```
GetJoinedAlbum()->where('........')
```

Comment: You can and should use `with`. You just need to know what constraints you want on which table - read this, for there's all you need to know http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

**Eager loading**

Try to use eager loding

```
$user->with('album.photos.tags');
```

**Raw query**

```
$yourBaseQuery = $query->join(...)->join(...)->where(...)->getQuery();
```

Than, from query you can get bindings, wheres, and joins.

```
   $joins = $yourBaseQuery->joins;
   $wheres = $yourBaseQuery->wheres;
   $bindings = $yourBaseQuery->getBindings();
   $anotherQuery = $query->join(...)->join(...)->where(...)->getQuery();
   $anotherQuery->joins = array_merge($joins, $anotherQuery->joins);
   $anotherQuery->mergeWheres($wheres, $bindings);
   $result = $anotherQuery->first(); // or all, or continure build your query.
```

So, your anotherQuery will be have joins, wheres and bindings from your first query

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Laravel eager loading to get all the results.

Getting user all albums, then all albums photos and then photos tags.

```
User::with(['albums.photos.tags'])->where('username',$user)->firstOrFail();
```

You can even query the nested relation like

```
return User::with(['albums' => function($query){
            $query->where('id',1);
        }])->where('username',$user)->firstOrFail();
```

See more about [Eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: I can't use with because I would like to continue querying the result from outside the scope of the function. See updated question.

Comment: You can query further also. Just see the above example I am using eager loading but I am also quering the user model further whew I am fetching the user by its username and in the second example I am querying relation you can also pass variables to this anonymous function like `function($query) use ($anyvariable) { }`

Comment: Yes I saw, but I can't chain a query to the joined table. (User::with('albums')->where('id', 1)) and I want the function to return a query-able object. If I "join", then I'll be able to chain any query.